# UITextView or UILabel with html hyperlinks

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I need text with multiple tapeable links init.
In Android I just used simple html string for that
Example:

```
"<a href=\"https://www.link.com\">Photo</a> The owner / <a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en\">CC BY-SA 3.0</a>"
```

And it worked only when I clicked on words corresponding links.

I spent a day and did not manage to find simple solution for ios. 
I tried to use extension for UITextView :

```
extension UITextView {
func setHTMLFromString(text: String) {
    let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, text)



    let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraph.alignment = .center


    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: modifiedFont.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
        documentAttributes: nil)

    self.attributedText = attrStr
}
```

But links work not only when I click on the hyperlink world but also when I click on simple text between. And I did not manage to align this text in textView(center) as well.

Does anybody know correct way?

Comment: I have gathered many excellent answers on this topic and created a small blob on GithHub It's very simple to integrate and use.
I don't want to go into too much details since it's all been already explained thoroughly in above answers.
My solution is based on those answers. [HyperlinkedUILabel](https://github.com/Yoorque/HyperlinkedUILabel/blob/prod/HyperlinkUILabel.swift)

Answer (score 1):

Can't find documentation at the moment, but close observation indicates:

Because tapping with a finger is not as precise as clicking with a mouse pointer, the link gets a larger "tap region" than the text itself.

With your example - "Photo The owner / CC BY-SA 3.0" - I can tap on the `ow` characters without triggering either link. If my tap is on `The` it triggers the Photo link, if my tap is on `new /` it triggers that link.

---

**Edit**

One option to center the text...

In your extension, change

```
let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, text)
```

to

```
let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<p style=\"text-align:center\"><span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span></p>" as NSString, text)
```

added the `<p style=...` tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe you know how to make alignment (center) in my extension?

Comment: @Dima - glad it worked for you. For the benefit of anyone else coming across your question, if this answered it you should mark the answer accepted.